# MySQL: Fast Word Count

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Consider the following MySQL function to count the number of words of a string:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`localhost` FUNCTION `wordcount`(`str` TEXT) RETURNS int(11)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE wordCnt, idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT 0;

    SET maxIdx=char_length(str);
    WHILE idx < maxIdx DO
        SET currChar=SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]';
        IF NOT prevChar AND currChar THEN
            SET wordCnt=wordCnt+1;
        END IF;
        SET prevChar=currChar;
        SET idx=idx+1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN wordCnt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Although this function seems to be working correctly, unfortunately it is much slower than its PHP counterpart `str_word_count()`. For example, while the MySQL function takes roughly 15s for a 60k characters text, the PHP function is almost instantaneous.

Any idea how to improve that?

Comment: An example of a task that is better done in a real programming language, not sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need an exact answer, you can get the rough answer using space counting techniques you will no doubt find elsewhere - basically assume the number of words is the number of spaces plus 1.  Since you often encounter double spaces between sentences, you can get a better value by first using [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace two spaces with one.  If you are already using mySQL 8, you can use [REGEX_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to convert any length of whitespace to a single space, which would clearly be better.  Here is an example (not using mySQL 8):

```
select length(replace(str, '  ', ' ')) - length(replace(str, ' ', '')) + 1 from ... where ...
```

It's not perfect, but for most plain text, its pretty good.  And it won't take 15 seconds.

EDIT: WRT your question in comments. if you need to get rid of control characters, et al, best I can come up with on 5.6 are multiple replacements.  For example:

```
select length(replace(replace(str, '\n', ' '), '  ', ' ')) - length(replace(replace(str, ' ', ''), '\n', '')) + 1 from ... where ...
```

It gets uglier after that.  If it needs to be more precise, I'd do whatever you are doing in PHP.  If you are looking for some target based on the word count in the database, use this as a "loose filter" to do the selection and then use PHP to do the precise filtering.  For example, if you are looking for things between 500 and 600 words, use this to look for 450 to 650, and then do the actual count in the selected rows to decide if they actually meet the criteria.

Comment: _"Here is an example (not using mySQL 8):"_ Thks, I'm still using 5.6.

Comment: _"you can get the rough answer using space counting techniques"_ You are correct, this is much faster.

Comment: _"Since you often encounter double spaces between sentences"_ You are correct, consecutive spaces or control symbols should be treated as only one.

Comment: Any idea how to replace consecutive spaces and/or control characters for one single space?

Comment: You can replace all of your common control symbols with empty strings on both sides - will still be fast, but gets a bit tedious:  length(replace(replace(replace...  This is why REGEX_REPLACE would be nice.

Comment: _"but gets a bit tedious:"_ This could also be done via WHILE loops. 1) replace ctrl chars with space. 2) replace consecutive space with one single space (repeat until there is no change).

Comment: I updated the answer.  Generally, I try to avoid using SQL for anything which can't be done in in one statement.  My experience with relational databases is relational is what they do well.  Procedural, not as much.

Comment: _"My experience with relational databases is relational is what they do well."_ Agree. However, for convenience, very often I prefer to bypass this rule.